# codeigniter - calling two functions from same controller one after the other, second function fails

Tags: php, codeigniter

This one's got me stuck!
I have two functions in a controller which can be called from a menu independantly and they work fine.
I want to call them in a month end routine (in the same controller), one after the other; the first function works fine and returns to the calling function, the second function is called but fails because the load of the $model variable fails.

Here is the code for the month end routine,

```
function month_end_routines()
{
    // create stock inventory valuation report in excel format
    $export_excel                   =   1;
    $this                           ->  inventory_summary($export_excel);

    // create negative stock
    $export_excel                   =   1; 
    $this                           ->  inventory_negative_stock($export_excel);
    echo 'debug 2';

    // reset rolling inventory indicator
    $this                           ->  load->model('Item');
    $this                           ->  load->library('../controllers/items');
    $this                           ->  items->reset_rolling();
}
```

Here is the code for the first function called inventory_summary,

```
function inventory_summary($export_excel=0, $create_PO=0, $set_NM=0, $set_SM=0)
{
    // load appropriate models and libraries
    $this                           ->  load->model('reports/Inventory_summary');
    $this                           ->  load->library('../controllers/items');

    // set variables

    $model                          =   $this->Inventory_summary;
    $tabular_data                   =   array();
    $edit_file                      =   'items/view/';
    $width                          =   $this->items->get_form_width();
    $stock_total                    =   0;

    // get all items
    $report_data                    =   $model->getData(array());

    foreach($report_data as $row)
    {
        $stock_value                =   $row['cost_price'] * $row['quantity'];
        $stock_total                =   $stock_total + $stock_value;

        // set up the item_number to handle blanks
        if ($row['item_number'] == NULL) {$row['item_number'] = $this->lang->line('common_edit');}

        $tabular_data[] = array     (
                                    $row['category'],
                                    anchor  (
                                            $edit_file.$row['item_id'].'/width:'.$width, 
                                            $row['item_number'],
                                            array('class'=>'thickbox','title'=>$this->lang->line('items_update'))
                                            ),
                                    $row['reorder_policy'],
                                    $row['name'], 
                                    $row['cost_price'], 
                                    $row['quantity'], 
                                    $stock_value, 
                                    $stock_total
                                    );
    }

    $today_date                     =   date('d/m/Y; H:i:s', time());

    $data = array   (
                    "title"         =>  $this->lang->line('reports_inventory_summary_report'),
                    "subtitle"      =>  ' - '.$today_date.' '.$this->lang->line('common_for').' '.$this->db->database.'.',
                    "headers"       =>  $model->getDataColumns(),
                    "data"          =>  $tabular_data,
                    "summary_data"  =>  $model->getSummaryData(array()),
                    "export_excel"  =>  $export_excel
                    );

    if ($export_excel == 1)
    {
        $this->load->model('Common_routines');
        $this->Common_routines->create_csv($data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view("reports/tabular", $data);
    }

    return;
```

.. and here is the code for the second function,

```
function inventory_negative_stock($export_excel=0, $create_PO=0, $set_NM=0, $set_SM=0)
{
    echo 'debug 1.5';
    $this                           ->  load->model('reports/Inventory_negative_stock');
    $this                           ->  load->library('../controllers/items');
    echo 'debug 1.6';

    $model                          =   $this->Inventory_negative_stock;
    var_dump($model);
    $tabular_data                   =   array();
    $edit_file                      =   'items/view/';
    $width                          =   $this->items->get_form_width();
    echo 'debug 1.7';
    $report_data                    =   $model->getData(array());
    echo 'debug 1.8';
    foreach($report_data as $row)
    {

        // set up the item_number to handle blanks
        if ($row['item_number'] == NULL) {$row['item_number'] = $this->lang->line('common_edit');}

        // load each line to the output array
        $tabular_data[] = array(
                                $row['category'],
                                anchor  (
                                        $edit_file.$row['item_id'].'/width:'.$width, 
                                        $row['item_number'],
                                        array('class'=>'thickbox','title'=>$this->lang->line('items_update'))
                                        ),
                                $row['name'],
                                $row['cost_price'], 
                                $row['quantity']
                                );
    }

    // load data array for display
    $today_date                     =   date('d/m/Y; H:i:s', time());
    $data = array   (
                    "title"         => $this->lang->line('reports_negative_stock'),
                    "subtitle"      => ' - '.$today_date.' '.$this->lang->line('common_for').' '.$this->db->database.'.',
                    "headers"       => $model->getDataColumns(),
                    "data"          => $tabular_data,
                    "summary_data"  => $model->getSummaryData(array()),
                    "export_excel"  => $export_excel
                    );

    if ($export_excel == 1)
    {
        $this->load->model('Common_routines');
        $this->Common_routines->create_csv($data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view("reports/tabular", $data);
    }

    return;
}
```

This line is failing
$model=$this->Inventory_negative_stock;

In the first function $model is loaded correctly. In the second it isn't.

It does not matter in which order these functions are called; $model always fails to load in the second function called.

Any help would be great and thanks in advance. I hope I've given enough code; if you need more information let me know.

As requested, here is the code in Inventory_negative_stock,

```
<?php
require_once("report.php");
class Inventory_negative_stock extends Report
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getDataColumns()
    {

        return array    (
                        $this->lang->line('reports_category'), 
                        $this->lang->line('reports_item_number'), 
                        $this->lang->line('reports_item_name'), 
                        $this->lang->line('reports_cost_price'), 
                        $this->lang->line('reports_count')
                        );
    }

    public function getData(array $inputs)
    {
        $this->db->select('category, name, cost_price, quantity, reorder_level, reorder_quantity, item_id, item_number');
        $this->db->from('items');
        $this->db->where("quantity < 0 and deleted = 0");
        $this->db->order_by('category, name');

        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }

    public function getSummaryData(array $inputs)
    {
        return array();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have an error ? Can you post the content of Inventory_negative_stock ?

Comment: have you tried to use lowercase? $this->inventory_negative_stock

Comment: Hi Vincent, no I have no error, just get to a blank screen. I updated the post to show the content of Inventory_negative_stock.

Comment: Hi Dimitris, No I haven't tried with lower case since both Inventory_summary and Inventory_negative_stock are models, but I will try. No joy, as expected.

Comment: Just a precision, both routines work fine when called independantly. When called one after the other from the month end routine the second one always fails to load the $model variable. It doesn't matter in which order I call the routines; its the second one called that fails. I have tried replacing $model with the full expression $this->Inventory_negative_stock but that doesn't work either. I think this is a codeigniter issue; somehow it is loosing track. Could something be changing in $this?

Comment: Ok, I solved the issue by combining the above two odels into one. Month end routine works fine now. Thanks for your answers. I was not able to find out why my original code was not working. With a single model it now is.